# How do I remedy "The "Copy" task does not support copying directories" in azure-devops build step?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, blazor-server-side, msbuild-task

From what I've gathered, the only change made since the last build in Azure-DevOps is the version of this nuget-package.
So either there is a mistake made in there (which I am not privy to investigate) or the problem lies elsewhere in the build task.

> [error]f:\WorkB_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(237,5):
> Error MSB3025: The source file
> "C:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService.nuget\packages\package\version\staticwebassets\css\open-iconic\FONT-LICENSE"
> is actually a directory.  The "Copy" task does not support copying
> directories.

The error is clear enough I suppose, but I haven´t found a resource on what is causing it or how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, Could you share the .csproj file and build arguments here? In addition, which agent are you using? Hosted agent or self-hosted agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a file ending (`css\open-iconic\FONT-LICENSE.txt`) the build could proceed.
However, why this was suddenly an issue still perplexes me.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: This will not work when such a file is inside a NuGet.

Comment: What file did you add this to?

Comment: @tzg I added the file ending to FONT-LICENSE

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is something wrong with Copy Task from your <packages_id>.props file,

Copy task should work with files rather than a folder, so you should use this:

```
<ItemGroup>
           <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)xxx\staticwebassets\assets\libs\flot-charts\Makefile\*.*"></File>
    </ItemGroup>
    
<Target Name="xxx" AfterTargets="xxx">
     <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFolder="xxx"></Copy>

</Target>
```

We could also copy the file via task [copy file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).